# Vega does not correctly read timestamps from python `time.time()`

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have the following vega chart:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "name": "data",
    "values": [
      {
        "action_hidden_size": 128,
        "async_envs": true,
        "charts_path": "charts/sweep",
        "entropy_coef": 0.01,
        "env": "BreakoutNoFrameskip-v0",
        "episode length": 168.8265306122449,
        "episode return": 1.0714285714285714,
        "epsilon": 0.0001,
        "fps": 427.7912197785782,
        "gamma": 0.99,
        "gpt": "1558M",
        "gradient norm": 0.04117301106452942,
        "jit": true,
        "lambda_": 1,
        "learning_rate": 0.0009,
        "log_interval": 100,
        "log_level": "INFO",
        "logger": "hasura",
        "loss": -0.028508108109235764,
        "num_envs": 16,
        "num_steps": 5,
        "resnet": false,
        "rnn": false,
        "run ID": 1459,
        "seed": 0,
        "step": 64000,
        "subcommand": "sweep",
        "sweep_id": 19,
        "time": 1625243790.698869,
        "training_steps": -1
      },
      {
        "action_hidden_size": 64,
        "async_envs": true,
        "charts_path": "charts/sweep",
        "entropy_coef": 0.01,
        "env": "BreakoutNoFrameskip-v0",
        "episode length": 178.2111111111111,
        "episode return": 1.288888888888889,
        "epsilon": 0.00001,
        "fps": 437.3014892700601,
        "gamma": 0.99,
        "gpt": "1558M",
        "gradient norm": 0.0920964702963829,
        "jit": true,
        "lambda_": 1,
        "learning_rate": 0.0005,
        "log_interval": 100,
        "log_level": "INFO",
        "logger": "hasura",
        "loss": 0.008676287718117237,
        "num_envs": 16,
        "num_steps": 10,
        "resnet": false,
        "rnn": false,
        "run ID": 1456,
        "seed": 0,
        "step": 64000,
        "subcommand": "sweep",
        "sweep_id": 23,
        "time": 1625243788.6341043,
        "training_steps": -1
      },
      {
        "action_hidden_size": 64,
        "async_envs": true,
        "charts_path": "charts/sweep",
        "entropy_coef": 0.01,
        "env": "BreakoutNoFrameskip-v0",
        "episode length": 178.75581395348837,
        "episode return": 1.430232558139535,
        "epsilon": 0.00001,
        "fps": 462.03207466360925,
        "gamma": 0.99,
        "gpt": "1558M",
        "gradient norm": 0.041478127241134644,
        "jit": true,
        "lambda_": 1,
        "learning_rate": 0.0005,
        "log_interval": 100,
        "log_level": "INFO",
        "logger": "hasura",
        "loss": 0.0075914873741567135,
        "num_envs": 16,
        "num_steps": 10,
        "resnet": false,
        "rnn": false,
        "run ID": 1452,
        "seed": 0,
        "step": 64000,
        "subcommand": "sweep",
        "sweep_id": 23,
        "time": 1625243776.3521159,
        "training_steps": -1
      },
      {
        "action_hidden_size": 128,
        "async_envs": true,
        "charts_path": "charts/sweep",
        "entropy_coef": 0.01,
        "env": "BreakoutNoFrameskip-v0",
        "episode length": 161.39583333333334,
        "episode return": 0.9166666666666666,
        "epsilon": 0.0001,
        "fps": 271.2519726477831,
        "gamma": 0.99,
        "gpt": "1558M",
        "gradient norm": 0.0941310003399849,
        "jit": true,
        "lambda_": 1,
        "learning_rate": 0.0009,
        "log_interval": 100,
        "log_level": "INFO",
        "logger": "hasura",
        "loss": -0.025099074468016624,
        "num_envs": 16,
        "num_steps": 5,
        "resnet": false,
        "rnn": false,
        "run ID": 1455,
        "seed": 0,
        "step": 32000,
        "subcommand": "sweep",
        "sweep_id": 19,
        "time": 1625243760.262077,
        "training_steps": -1
      },
      {
        "action_hidden_size": 128,
        "async_envs": true,
        "charts_path": "charts/sweep",
        "entropy_coef": 0.01,
        "env": "BreakoutNoFrameskip-v0",
        "episode length": 156.8181818181818,
        "episode return": 0.8863636363636364,
        "epsilon": 0.0001,
        "fps": 279.50948832177323,
        "gamma": 0.99,
        "gpt": "1558M",
        "gradient norm": 0.06209081411361694,
        "jit": true,
        "lambda_": 1,
        "learning_rate": 0.0009,
        "log_interval": 100,
        "log_level": "INFO",
        "logger": "hasura",
        "loss": -0.02385426126420498,
        "num_envs": 16,
        "num_steps": 5,
        "resnet": false,
        "rnn": false,
        "run ID": 1459,
        "seed": 0,
        "step": 32000,
        "subcommand": "sweep",
        "sweep_id": 19,
        "time": 1625243755.579455,
        "training_steps": -1
      }
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "type": "temporal",
      "field": "time"
    },
    "y": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "field": "episode return"
    },
    "color": {
      "type": "nominal",
      "field": "run ID"
    }
  },
  "height": 400,
  "mark": "line",
  "width": 600
}
```

Here is a [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqULKQI4aFWpRLiSQQzgQ0AbVBIomdrID6MGsuVxnEGgC89qAEYAJgAOJSQIAE9ZKCdPYktUTAAncyVYJGTMCCccNRh9DKyITgB3ODgcRRBPFLYcSKcoNjgAMzQABkoOgKV4-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-LEYKwqippdpBHaBamYqpy3Fc9Kqh2GpodqCC6kg+qBIaIyAj+FpqNaWlNgmjrEZGrruh0nrenAvr6IGIZhl6EZRugMYQHGZVJmK6anCCpyhCSAQZlKuYgtWpbxIkZw9bW9b9XlIAtm2HaDsOY39mgU1oakY6TtOYhViAc57qNf6rs867rZubDbru+gHgR1SnZUZ57rmH40NegQtXeD6vpQgUSuKtwfgs35mkNaloABwGgQ4cgQe4ni1jBO3wdEsR9eqqHpLhmF5AJ6HIyUF2ETRJGNM0bRitR-ToEMIzjJMMzzIsbErGsGySTxfFmgJUoXCCjkBLcbx3EZIQPgzPy8X8sknJQ94dLmt7spz3N5giNBIkCNq2jpDbPC13S3D5ILq4F5k5ulVLWV0tkMvZ6CsuyXKUi5ApCiKYoSs8pLBCCLySrc6uvCqaooZqkXRbF1FGolv2WqltrpQ6Z5ZS6pi5flTg+nAfogCVob5RV0axgsdWJMr7MEkZ0o66yTWc+lxa9eW-VrVXf0NpmzYWBNc3dgts2du3I5LVOgTyhS60VJtS71jte01UwW7IMd+4nudJ5XWgN0gFe-hnLeLwPs1lB5iJrKXt9Jq-X+yZASBIB2CDziuOD0F+CcoQw4h8N+2hGE5KjBToB-+FHjjyR6h43IoTIixA6Jk0YpTFiSxaacQFnsA4zNv5nHklzdktxMFYKwYWGo3FBa7GFoCWkZxThkPIRQ8h8tFYNQsrpZeYJhJiCJG7PypJbjUSNhoE29JGQdhAJbJyNskB8jth5MUSpOaZjRJgukIR3g+zCojLUOo9QGi1AlY+5pw60PtF6GOzocqBA9BlJOhUU7FSDBnDKWcqo53jEieqqAUzdFvHaN4HQdbqxCD0MhLxBqvwGiAeup80DpXGu2NuQ4O4Dm7mNUc44+7gjZEuYei51pj1QFrCeB0jp7nWvPY8BEl6BEvHddej0t7NS6NcbW3VV5HySqE5x59gbgVvlBSGD9AhP0vghOGNcEaag-lhNGv8sabGIoA0i+MKJUTARAhiFNmLU3YnTLiUleJIKOCg1alx2oHIzEc9qCChYyWIZpV8etbjXNubgtSCsNLKzoQ2II+JKBiDtLzLWUppQry4bSXh5sBGOWtgyW2bl7aeRtC1O0WYJSc0eM+XBoUhkRVUTFdRIctHJStLoxOTpsrx2MaNaOydU7pzKmQWxGB7F5wBqmIKYgISPGuBCcUL4AmDIeoNZp4SW6RK7tEvssThXxN7itWcaTKKjxXFknyJjJ7Tx3PkiZRTLrnlKbde6G8nrswkFCJUKSGlfhxc0wGABdYCNFmh8jNGgUAAAPB1q9Ig4H8KvRAOBhTxwxPyQQ+S14gGtZEF1mA3UeoAI4MB3A4dQDhSDVFaP6-JWxGZEPkNa5oSJKqgHDe6-QQoECml9SAZNKd8mLUScG618AaBkCwNiExyBkijH0MINs1RShuAEuZDogEgA) to a vega editor with this chart.

As you can see, the time-stamps do not appear to be rendering correctly. The "time" fields are derived from python's `time.time()` method. Should I be using a different format?

According to the [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/type.html), vega should accept a "a timestamp number (e.g., 1552199579097)` for "temporal" fields.

I've also looked at [this issue](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/2439) which seems to indicate that this should work in the latest Vega, although per that issue, I am not sure if I need a field along the lines of

```
    "format": {
      "parse": {
        "date": "number"
      }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `time.time()` returns a timestamp in [seconds](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) since the zero epoch.

Javascript timestamps are expected to be in [milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) since the zero epoch.

So, to correctly use Python timestamps in vega-lite charts, you'll have to multiply them by 10^6:

```json
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "1000000 * datum.time", "as": "time"}
  ],
```